# Create custom tag in config file?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, config, app-config

To make sure that correct version of config file is used with the correct version of the software I need to add a key tag to the config file.

There is a appSettings but it to obvious to look for the key here, the user could copy this with easy from an old config file.

What I am looking for is a way to create my own tag in the config file that are not as obvious.

I have only found [Custom Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.140).aspx), it this the only way?

Comment: Do you really need another way? What's wrong with Custom Sections?

Comment: It is duable but I would like a custom tag if its possible, its not that obviousfor the user what the custom tag really is.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security at all. Why are the users actually going in and fiddling with these values?

Comment: With custom sections you can have a custom tag. If you need to hide something from the user why don't you encrypt the appSettings section?

Comment: Some settings of the config file have to be setup based on environment. Is it possible to encrypt parts of the appSettings section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a GUID as custom tag name as well as the version number (maybe map it to a simple number in your source code).

That's still not really "secure" but it's not obvious what this tag could mean.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, how do I do this then?

Comment: You could just add a new setting row to the appsettings (according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) and use some GUID (without dashes and beginning with A-Z) as a name. Another GUID as string value.
If you don't want to use appsettings from .net, you could also store your settings in a binary config file using BinaryFormatter/Serialization.